# How to set the selected item in a ListCtrl?

Tags: python, wxpython

How do I set an item as the selected item programmatically, given its index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the ListCtrl method [Select](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ListCtrl-class.html#Select)

```
Select(self, idx, on=1)

[de]select an item
```

Comment: OP's addition: `wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL` to allow just one item to be selected